# Converting a list of objects to an array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Given I have a list of objects:

```json
{
  "alpha": {
    "bytes": {
      "value": 4789440
    },
    "doc_count": 7723
  },
  "beta": {
    "bytes": {
      "value": 4416862639
      },
    "doc_count": 1296
  }
}
```

Is there a way using `jq` to get an array representation of this, such as:

```json
  [
    {
      "key": "alpha",
      "bytes": {
        "value": 4789440
      },
      "doc_count": 7723
    },
    {
      "key": "beta",
      "bytes": {
        "value": 4416862639
      },
      "doc_count": 1296
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Neither of your desired output formats are valid JSON (fields only exist in objects such as `{"a":1}`, not in arrays (`["a":1]` is not valid). You can, however, have an array of objects `[{"a":1},{"b":2}]` if this is what you want.

Comment: @pmf You are totally right, sorry for that... I have updated the question with a correct example result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `to_entries` would be one way. By accessing `.key` and `.value`, the composition would be:

```sh
jq '[to_entries[] | {key} + .value]' input.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "key": "alpha",
    "bytes": {
      "value": 4789440
    },
    "doc_count": 7723
  },
  {
    "key": "beta",
    "bytes": {
      "value": 4416862639
    },
    "doc_count": 1296
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kyw1qByv63)

Answer (score 1):

```
[ keys_unsorted[] as $key | { $key } + .[$key] ]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YCpt6W1FRr) on jqplay

or

```
to_entries | map( { key } + .value )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lvpIXiDwXA) on jqplay